# Understanding GitHub branches - which branch to use to submit to App Store?

Tags: github, audiokit

I'm just about have my first App ready to send to be validated by AppStore. My build is currently using the develop branch of AudioKit. Should I be submitting using the main branch?
I'm running Xcode 13 and the main branch just causes loads of errors.Should probably have stuck in Xcode 12!

I guess the answer must be the latest main branch but I'm a bit unsure

Also I'm wonder if and how to credit AudioKit?

Or indeed generally how does one credit 3rd party frameworks? if at all?

I have an "About" view in the App itself and was just going to put "Built using AudioKit" there and on the App Store details. Can't find any other decent example on the App Store to go by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a release version of AudioKit so that your builds are tied to a specific release.  AudioKit is free and open-source and we don't require you to give us any credit, but if you do that it's very nice.

Comment: Thank you. Nice to get an answer from the boss! AudioKit is truly awesome by the way - I would feel rude not to credit you. So I should install a specific release version ie as of today 5.2.2?

Comment: Yeah, develop and 5.2.2 are the same right now.